# Proper SVN workflow for bugfix on an old commit

Tags: svn, version-control

My team and I are working off a codebase that uses SVN for version control.  This is my first time using SVN; prior to this I've used Git exclusively.  Today we showcased the version of our app which is hosted on our QA server for the product owner, although the latest (local) version of the codebase is several commits ahead of this QA version.  The product owner spotted several bugs that need fixing, and wants the fixes for these pushed into production immediately.  However she has not yet approved the changes that we've committed since this QA version (43 commits).

Obviously it would be a lot of work to revert those commits, make the bug fix, and re-implement those commits manually.  I can't imagine my team and I are the first ones to have encountered this problem, so I assume there is a best practice somewhere out there.  But as I'm unfamiliar with non-distributed version control systems, I'm not sure how to proceed so as to avoid my team shooting itself in the foot.  So my question is in two parts:

a) How can my team and I extract ourselves from this situation while preserving the work we've done?
b) What workflow could we have used to avoid this problem?

Comment: The good old branches...? If I understand your description correctly you are doing all of this on a single branch (trunk?).

Comment: @reto- that's correct.

Comment: IMHO this question is mainly 'verbose' but not "opinion-based". It has a clear question for a problem which can be directly be answered. OP: Try to make the question even more technical and briefer, describe the situation, describe the desired 'outcome'. It boils down to that you would like 'To implement fixes on a old revision without losing any work between this revision and now'

Comment: note: you can create branches of old revisions using `svn cp svn://localhost/project/trunk@123 svn://localhost/project/branches/customer-demo-version/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Obviously it would be a lot of work to revert those commits, make the bug fix, and re-implement those commits manually.

Actually, with Subversion it isn't assuming the following conditions are true:

1. You're doing all your work in a single branch (or trunk)
2. The code you need to change from pre-QA wasn't changed post-QA.

For argument's sake, let's say you showed the product owner revision 100, and your subsequent commits have pushed the repository revision number to 43.

#### Steps

1. Check out a fresh working copy of your code (not 100% necessary, but this will make things cleaner)
2. Roll back the last 43 revisions with a [reverse merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo). `svn merge -rHEAD:100 URL_TO_PROJECT_IN_REPOSITORY .` and commit it. This will undo all of the changes made between those 2 points in time, and creates revision 144.
3. Make your bug fixes and commit them. Again, to make things easy, we'll check it all in with a single commit. This creates revision 145.
4. Push your changes out to QA
5. Roll back your rollback. `svn merge -c -144 URL_TO_PROJECT_IN_REPOSITORY`. Then commit this to the repository. This creates revision 146, which is revision 143 **plus** the bug fixes that your product owner found.

This would be a bit easier if you were creating branches or tags for your releases to your various environments (as Ben mentions in his answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual way of moving forward would be to create a "stable" or "release" branch from the point where you showed your product owner the code. Fix any "must fix" issues there and then merge them forward to trunk to get the fixes there as well. Once all the "must fix" issues are done and the code is ready to ship, make a tag off the branch as well.

A workflow to avoid the situation would be to always create a "stable" branch when you're almost ready to release something. No unapproved changes go on the stable branch, only "must fix" issues for the release. Merge as before when you make fixes to the stable/release branch. When you show your build to your project owner as a release candidate, don't show them trunk; show them the "stable" branch instead.

Note, this also lets you "back port" any fixes made on trunk at a later date, if your customer decides they really really want a bugfix made on trunk but not all the new features.

Comment: I assume "trunk" is the SVN equivalent of "HEAD" in Git, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't really use Git. That's probably right... It's equivalent to "default" branch in Mercurial ;-) Some overview here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout and here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.maint.html#svn.branchmerge.maint.layout

SVN has its own "HEAD" concept, meaning "the latest revision committed to the repository", it doesn't relate to branches of development.

Comment: Yes, that's what HEAD means in Git as well.  Since you mean the default branch, then "trunk" would be equivalent to "master" in Git.  Thanks for the clarification.